# Can conditional build symbols logic be defined in a library and use the executable symbols in C#?

Tags: c#

I have logic that uses preprocessor directives to identify build config (debug, staging, release, etc.).

I would like to reuse that logic, defining it once in a library and calling it from executables.

The logic is something like this:

```
public BuildConfig GetBuildConfig()
{
#if DEBUG
            return BuildConfig.Debug;
#elif STAGING
            return BuildConfig.Staging;
#else
            return BuildConfig.Release;
#endif
}
```

I defined that method in a class that lives in library 'A'and im calling that method from executable 'B'

From executable 'B' i reference library 'A' in debug build

The problem is from executable 'B' i get BuildConfig.Debug when its build config was Staging or Release. I mean, im getting 'A' build config, instead of 'B'.

Is there a way to execute logic in 'A' and get the 'B' build mode or symbols?

I tried making the class in 'A' static, and also making it non-static and instanciating it from 'B' with the same result...

Comment: Preprocessor directives do not work that way, no. You would have to actively rebuild the library alongside the applications, and set the symbols for the solution as a whole. If that's not desirable, you have to build separate versions of the libraries, and refer to the appropriate instance on building. This can be done by using a build variable in the project file.

Comment: "Is there a way to execute logic in 'B' and get the 'A' build mode or symbols?" - that's what you're already getting. I suspect you mean the other round, don't you?

Comment: I know it's just an example, but that kind of configuration change should be in appsettings, not code.

Comment: @Neil Ok, i will explain my requirements:
In every project i have a ContainerConfig class that uses Autofac to resolve dependencies, and it resolve different dependencies based on the build config.
So, in each ContainerConfig of each project i had this preprocessor logic, so i wanted to reuse that logic, defining it on a library, and i faced this problem...

Comment: Right - at that point, basically Jeroen's comment is the appropriate one. Preprocessor directives change what is built into the DLL. Once the library A has been built, *one* of those paths has been chosen - there's no sign left of the rest of them.

Comment: Sure, but if you had this code but instead of hard coding it, you read the BuildConfig value from appsettings (via IConfiguration etc), then your dlls would contain ALL the possible code, but at runtime, it would wire up AutoFac to whatever the configuration is.

Comment: @Neil You're arguing with Jon Skeet, who literally wrote the book on C#. I don't think you're going to teach him anything he doesn't already know. :)

Comment: I'm not teaching JS, I'm giving an alternative answer to the OPs problem.  JS is giving a different answer.  (Anyway, I taught JS everything he knows :-) )